# IIS 7/MSSQL Server debugging

Tags: sql-server, wcf, iis

I am developing a WCF service, so far I have added only a few simple interfaces.  Testing the service in the VS debug environment, all is well.
When I published the service to IIS 7 for further testing, all was fine, at least after I added db_datareader and db_datawriter permissions to the relevant databases for user IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0.
Now the service is failing silently. Calling the service through a browser, I get the following message: "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details." Fiddler says this is a result of an HTTP 400 error message (Bad Request).
I rolled back the code to return a hard-coded value, so I am sure that the issue is at the DB level, not the IIS 7 server installation.
The problem is that the Event Viewer shows no meaningful error messages. This despite the fact that all the code is surrounded by try/catch, with any exception caught going to the event viewer.
There is one message stating "Starting up database 'ReportServer$SQLEXPRESSTempDB'", but as far as I can tell that appears every 10 minutes, without reference to any attempts to access the database. Just to make sure, I gave the .NET 4 user R/W permission to access that DB as well.
In addition, I don't see any messages in the SQL Server Logs.
How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that  db_datareader and db_datawriter permissions are not enough to run stored procedures. I upgraded the permissions and all was good.
The only thing I don't understand is why the exception wasn't written to the event log.